# Regex expression for a particular pattern

Tags: python, regex, string

So I have occurrence of strings starting with `\u` followed by various forms of 4 character hexadecimals **(They are not unicode objects, but actual strings in the data, which is why I would like to clean up the data)** and would like to replace that occurrences with white spaces.

Example textfile: `Hello \u2022 Created, reviewed, \u00e9executed and maintained`

**For eg:** there would be occurrences of strings `\u2022` and `\u00e9`, I would like to find `\u` and remove it along with the 4 character substring `2022` and `00e9` followed after that. I'm looking for an adequate regex for this pattern.

Example Code:

```
import json
import io
import re

files = glob('Candidate Profile Data/*')

for file_ in files:
    with io.open(file_, 'r', encoding='us-ascii') as json_file:
        json_data = json_file.read().decode()
        json_data = re.sub('[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ',json_data)
        json_data = json_data.replace('\\n',' ')
        json_data = re.sub(r'\\u[0-9a-f]{,4}',' ',json_data)

        print json_data
        json_data = json.loads(json_data)
        print(json_data)
```

Comment: If I'm getting it right, you need to remove unicode characters from a string?

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì No, which is why I have explicitly mentioned that they are not ACTUAL unicode characters, but in form of strings in the data itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, we need an example of your code, but as a pointer, the regex i think you'll need is something like `r'\\u[0-9a-f]{,4}'`

Here is an example of it in use:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string='Hello \\u2022 Created, reviewed, \\u00e9executed and maintained'
>>> my_string
'Hello \\u2022 Created, reviewed, \\u00e9executed and maintained'
>>> re.sub(r'\\u[0-9a-f]{,4}',"",my_string)
'Hello  Created, reviewed, executed and maintained'
```

Would still like to see an example of your CODE so that we can provide a more accurate answer

Comment: Yes it worked after I added the preceding 'r', thought it wasn't needed. I just added an example code of what I'm trying to do. If you could merge my code into a single regex expression, I would be grateful for that.